# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') , using useHistory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to the react js, while trying to fetch the page from different components using **(trying to fetch dashboard component from loginform component and the loginform component is inside the landing page)** **history.push()** I am getting this error.

**(app.js)**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LandingPage from "./Pages/LandingPage/LandingPage";
import DashBoard from "./Pages/Dashboard/dashBoard";


export default function App(){
    return(
        
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
                <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

***(login page)***
**here I m facing the issue in login method**

```
import React, { useRef, useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import $ from 'jquery';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import {useHistory,withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import './LF.css';
import LoginLogo from './zmtLogo.png';

var LoginForm = (props) => {

let history = useHistory();

var Login = async ()=>{
        if(LoginData.email !== '' & LoginData.pass!== ''){

            history.push("/dashboard")

        }else{
            swal({
                title: "Incomplite fillup",
                icon: "warning"
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="l_main" ref={LOGbox}>

                <div className="login">
                    <p>Login Here!</p>

                    <div className="fillup">
                        <i className="far fa-envelope"></i>
                        <input onChange={LoginFillup} value={LoginData.email} id="userid" name="userid" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="fillup">
                        <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                        <input onChange={LoginFillup} value={LoginData.pass} id="pass" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="password" />
                        <i className="fas fa-eye" id="eye"></i>
                    </div>

                    <button onClick={Login}>Login</button>
                    <p id="signup">don't have an account?<span id="click_1" onClick={LeftSlider}>create</span> </p>
                    <p id="fo_p">Forget password</p>

                    
                </div>
                {/* <!-- .................................................................................................. --> */}
                <div className="signup">
                    <p>Signup Here!</p>

                    <div className="fillup">
                        <i className="fas fa-users"></i>
                        <input onChange={signupFillup} value={SignUpData.userName} id="user_name" name="user_name" type="text" placeholder="name" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="fillup">
                        <i className="far fa-envelope"></i>
                        <input onChange={signupFillup} value={SignUpData.email} id="user_em" name="user_em" type="text" placeholder="email" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="fillup">
                        <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                        <input onChange={signupFillup} value={SignUpData.pass} id="user_pass" name="user_pass" type="password" placeholder="password" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="fillup">
                        <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                        <input onChange={signupFillup} value={SignUpData.pass2} id="user_pass_2" name="user_pass_2" type="password" placeholder="password(re type)" />
                    </div>

                    <button onClick={Signup}>Register</button>
                    <p id="login">Already have an account.<span id="click_2" onClick={RightSlider}>login</span> </p>

                   
                </div>
                {/* <!-- ................................................................................................--> */}
                <div className="slider">
                    <div className="img_area">
                        <div className="close_tab" onClick={props.closefunction}>
                            close
                        </div>
                        <div className="img_sec">
                            <img src={LoginLogo} alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some of the login page code, where are you declaring `history` and where is the start of the component?

Comment: sorry, it's my bad.  I have updated it please have a look.

Comment: Where is `LoginForm` being rendered? Is it within the `Router`?

Comment: its rendered inside landingpage component

Comment: I see, then using the `useHistory` hook and declaring `const history = useHistory();` should be sufficient. Have you made sure to kill any code watchers/hot reloaders? If the issue still persists think you could create a small codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: https://u4id2.csb.app/

Comment: just type any random things over the login form...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-star-u4id2?file=/src/components/LoginForm/LoginForm.jsx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you've structured your code as such, but the `LandingPage` is rendering the `LoginForm` into a separate DOM element rendered into a `reactDom.render` and thus isn't rendered within the routing context. `history` is indeed undefined.

> ```
> reactDom.render(
>   <LoginForm closefunction={ClosePopup} />,
>   document.getElementsByClassName("Lpopup")[0]
> );
> ```

Normally you would create a React portal, though, after inspecting the landing page logic I don't think this is necessary and suggest the following to fix:

LandingPage

Convert the `PopDisplay` state to a boolean to show/hide the "modal", and conditionally render the "Lpopup" div and `LoginForm`.

```
const [PopDisplay, setPopDisplay] = useState(false);

const DisplayPopup = () => {
  setPopDisplay(true);
};

const ClosePopup = () => {
  setPopDisplay(false);
};

...

{PopDisplay && (
  <div className="Lpopup" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <LoginForm closefunction={ClosePopup} />
  </div>
)}
```

Now that `LoginForm` is being rendered within the same app it should have access to the routing context and the `useHistory` hook should return a defined `history` object.

[image: Edit unhandled-rejection-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-p]

Answer (score 0):

In react router dom v6 useHistory has been replace by usenavigate hook.

so do

```js
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

const App=()=>{
const history=useNavigate()
   return <>....</>
}
```

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview
check out this

Or else downgrade the version of react-router-dom to make use of usehistory hook

Comment: If it was the case that OP was on RRDv6 then the `Switch` wouldn't work and there'd be plenty of errors about not rendering a `Route` into a `Routes` component and nothing being rendered on the `element` prop of the `Route`, `useHistory` would be undefined, etc... etc... I don't believe OP is using v6.

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",

Comment: after downgrading to 5.2.0. still it showing the same error